# Bind TextArea to String Array - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a class that has a property that is a string array.  I would like to bind the UI to a TextArea so that when a user enters text, each line in the text area is a string in the array of the class property.  Is there a way to do this, or some type of translator that could do it?

My first thought was maybe a pipe, but that only goes one way...

How would I do this conversion?

Comment: BTW yes I did Google it but couldn't find anything, perhaps searching for the wrong terms?

Comment: if i understand you this will work : 

<textarea matInput #text placeholder="Textarea" [formControl]="textArea"></textarea>

    strArr = ["asd", "asd", "asd"];
    textArea = new FormControl(this.strArr.join("\n"));

    this.textArea.valueChanges.subscribe(v =>{
      this.strArr = v.split("\n");
      console.log(this.strArr);
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the `FormsModule`, which means attaching an event listener to the `textarea`

```
<textarea ngModel (ngModelChange)="toArray($event)"></textarea>
```

And then, in your *Component* class

```
toArray(value: string): void {
   this.model.lines = value.split(/[\r\n]+/);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get ngModelChange to work, it didn't show up for me and didn't work when I forced it...  However I was able to do it with (changed) using the same idea.

Comment: @sfaust for ngModelChange, you need to import FormsModule.

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you!

Comment: Good. but doesn't support 2way binging. I mean you cant pass the model to it to show.